# Android environment in VS2015

Tags: android, sdk, visual-studio-2015, environment

try to build my first Android project in VS2015 and get the following error:

```
2>  D:\Work\Train2015\ARM\Debug\Package\build.xml:45: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure ANDROID_HOME environment variable is correctly set.
```

ANDROID_HOME was set in my Windows environment:

set ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\sdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this info will save your time:

1. In VS2015 open your solution
2. In Solution Explorer select your Packaging project and open its Properties
3. Select Ant
4. In Additional Parameters add the following:

-Dsdk.dir=path_to_Root_Android_SDK

For example, -Dsdk.dir=D:\Android\sdk

5. Make it for Release and Debug configuration.